# Unable to select item in Select2 drop down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I am working on an app that uses Select2 (version 3.5.1). The HTML to setup this drop down / autocomplete field looks like this:

```
<input id="mySelect" class="form-control" type="hidden">
```

The `form-control` class in this snippet comes from Bootstrap. I am initializing this field from JavaScript using the following:

```
function getItemFormat(item) {
  var format = '<div>' + item.ItemName + '</div>';
  return format;
}

$(function() {
  $('#mySelect').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 5,
    placeholder: 'Search for an item',
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
      url: '/api/getItems',
      dataType: 'json',
      quietMillis: 250,
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          query: term
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data, id: 'ItemId', text: 'ItemText' };
      }
    },
    formatResult: getItemFormat,
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
  });
});
```

When my select field loads, it successfully renders. Once I type at least the fifth character, it successfully pulls items from the server and lists them as options. However, if I try to select one of them, nothing happens. The drop-down popup stays open. Nothing gets put in the actual field. There are no errors in the JavaScript console. Its like I didn't click anything.

In addition, I noticed that nothing is highlighted when I put my mouse over an item or attempt to navigate the list of options with the arrow keys.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to be missing a quote on the mySelect section. Is that in your source? try adding it in and see if it helps

Comment: That's a problem with the snippet (I fixed it). However, that did not fix the issue.

Comment: @user70192 can you provide us a live example using JSFiddle ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

### What is happening:

By default, `results` of the object you are returning in `ajax.results` should be an array in this structure `[{id:1,text:"a"},{id:2,text:"b"}, ...]`.

```
  results: function (data, page) {
    var array = data.results; //depends on your JSON
    return { results: array };
  }
```

In [Select2.js](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js) it actually states:

```
* @param options.results a function(remoteData, pageNumber, query) that converts data returned form the remote request to the format expected by Select2.
*      The expected format is an object containing the following keys:
*      results array of objects that will be used as choices
*      more (optional) boolean indicating whether there are more results available
*      Example: {results:[{id:1, text:'Red'},{id:2, text:'Blue'}], more:true}
```

Reading the source code, we can see that `ajax.results` is called on AJAX success:

```
   success: function (data) {
                        // TODO - replace query.page with query so users have access to term, page, etc.
                        // added query as third paramter to keep backwards compatibility
                        var results = options.results(data, query.page, query);
                        query.callback(results);
                    }
```

So `ajax.results` is really just a function for you to format your data into the appropriate structure ( e.g. `[{id:a,text:"a"},{id:b,text:"b"}, ...]`) before the data is passed to `query.callback`:

```
 callback: this.bind(function (data) {

                    // ignore a response if the select2 has been closed before it was received
                    if (!self.opened()) return;


                    self.opts.populateResults.call(this, results, data.results, {term: term, page: page, context:context});
                    self.postprocessResults(data, false, false);

                    if (data.more===true) {
                        more.detach().appendTo(results).html(self.opts.escapeMarkup(evaluate(self.opts.formatLoadMore, self.opts.element, page+1)));
                        window.setTimeout(function() { self.loadMoreIfNeeded(); }, 10);
                    } else {
                        more.remove();
                    }
                    self.positionDropdown();
                    self.resultsPage = page;
                    self.context = data.context;
                    this.opts.element.trigger({ type: "select2-loaded", items: data });
                })});
```

And what `query.callback` eventually does is to set the logic up properly so that everything works fine when you choose one of the items and trigger `.selectChoice`.

```
selectChoice: function (choice) {

            var selected = this.container.find(".select2-search-choice-focus");
            if (selected.length && choice && choice[0] == selected[0]) {

            } else {
                if (selected.length) {
                    this.opts.element.trigger("choice-deselected", selected);
                }
                selected.removeClass("select2-search-choice-focus");
                if (choice && choice.length) {
                    this.close();
                    choice.addClass("select2-search-choice-focus");
                    this.opts.element.trigger("choice-selected", choice);
                }
            }
        }
```

So if there is some misconfiguration (e.g. `results` is not in the correct structure) that causes the class `.select2-search-choice-focus` not to be added to the DOM element before `.selectChoice` is called, this is what happens:

> The drop-down popup stays open. Nothing gets put in the actual field. There are no errors in the JavaScript console. Its like I didn't click anything.

---

### Solutions

There are many solutions to this. One of them is, of course, do some array keys manipulation in `ajax.results`.

```
  results: function (data, page) {
  //data = { results:[{ItemId:1,ItemText:"a"},{ItemId:2,ItemText:"b"}] };
    var array = data.results;
    var i = 0;
    while(i < array.length){
        array[i]["id"] = array[i]['ItemId'];
        array[i]["text"] = array[i]['ItemText'];
        delete array[i]["ItemId"];
        delete array[i]["ItemText"];
    i++;
    }
    return { results: array };
  }
```

But you may ask: why must the id be "id" and the text be "text" in the array?

```
[{id:1,text:"a"},{id:2,text:"b"}]
```

Can the array be in this structure instead?

```
[{ItemId:1,ItemText:"a"},{ItemId:2,ItemText:"b"}]
```

The answer is yes. You just need to overwrite the `id` and `text` functions with your own functions.

Here are the original functions for `.selecte2` in [Select2.js](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js):

```
    id: function (e) { return e == undefined ? null : e.id; },
    text: function (e) {
      if (e && this.data && this.data.text) {
        if ($.isFunction(this.data.text)) {
          return this.data.text(e);
        } else {
          return e[this.data.text];
        }
      } else {
        return e.text;
      }
    },
```

To overwrite them, just add your own functions inside the object you are passing to `.selecte2`:

```
$('#mySelect').select2({
id: function (item) { return item.ItemId },
text: function (item) { return item.ItemText }
......
});
```

---

### Updates

### What else is happening :

> However, the text of the selected item does not appear in the field after the list closes.

This means `.selectChoice` has been successfully executed. Now the problem lies in `.updateSelection`. In the source code:

```
   updateSelection: function (data) {

        var container=this.selection.find(".select2-chosen"), formatted, cssClass;

        this.selection.data("select2-data", data);

        container.empty();
        if (data !== null) {
            formatted=this.opts.formatSelection(data, container, this.opts.escapeMarkup);
        }
        if (formatted !== undefined) {
            container.append(formatted);
        }
        cssClass=this.opts.formatSelectionCssClass(data, container);
        if (cssClass !== undefined) {
            container.addClass(cssClass);
        }

        this.selection.removeClass("select2-default");

        if (this.opts.allowClear && this.getPlaceholder() !== undefined) {
            this.container.addClass("select2-allowclear");
        }
    }
```

From here we can see that, before the corresponding string of text is placed into the input, it would call `formatSelection`.

```
formatSelection: function (data, container, escapeMarkup) {
            return data ? escapeMarkup(this.text(data)) : undefined;
        },
```

### Update: Solution

Previously I thought `this.text(data)` can be overwritten by having `text: funcion(item){ ... }` in the parameters, but sadly it doesn't work that way.

Therefore to render the text properly in the field, you should overwrite `formatSelection` by doing

```
$('#mySelect').select2({
id: function (item) { return item.ItemId },
formatSelection: function (item) { return item.ItemText }
//......
});
```

instead of trying to overwrite `text` (which should supposedly have the same effect but this way of overwriting is not yet supported/implemented in the library)

```
$('#mySelect').select2({
id: function (item) { return item.ItemId },
text: function (item) { return item.ItemText }  //this will not work.
//......
});
```

Comment: This approach at least closes the drop down list. However, the text of the selected item does not appear in the field after the list closes. Why not?

Comment: @user70192 this is because of `formatSelection` function you have to provide, like I said in my answer below. I had the same issue reporducing the error

Comment: @user70192 I have updated my answer regarding that. Simply put it instead of having `text: function (item) { return item.ItemText }` we just need to change the `text into `formatSelection` like this:  `formatSelection: function (item) { return item.ItemText } ` and it would work.

Comment: @user70192 If there is still some problem after this, it would be great if you can let me know how the JSON the ajax call to `/api/getItems` looks like. You can get the JSON by doing `console.log(data)` in `ajax.results`. Actually, whether it would work properly depends highly on the structure of the JSON.

Comment: sorry to tell, but this answer actually killed my desire to ever use select2^^ i mean the answer may be correct, but the work to put into a simple display of an array is absolutely not worth the pain ;-)

Comment: Yes, this was a long answer but Archy demonstrates how to walk through this plugin and figure out what's going on with the code (a practice I know I need to do more often). I almost didn't read it but ultimately I am glad I did as it did help me find my problem but more so UNDERSTAND why my code wasn't working. A++

Comment: great answer, worth the bounty!

Answer (score 16):

The issue you are facing is that `select2` wants all your results to have an `id` property.  If they don't you need to initialise with an `id` function which returns the id from each result.

It will not allow you to select a result unless you satisfy one of these. So in the case of your example :

```
function getItemFormat(item) {
  var format = '<div>' + item.ItemName + '</div>';
  return format;
}

$(function() {
  $('#mySelect').select2({
    minimumInputLength: 5,
    placeholder: 'Search for an item',
    allowClear: true,
    id: function(item) { return item.ItemId; },    /* <-- ADDED FUNCTION */
    ajax: {
      url: '/api/getItems',
      dataType: 'json',
      quietMillis: 250,
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          query: term
        };
      },
      results: function (data, page) {
        return { results: data, id: 'ItemId', text: 'ItemText' };
      }
    },
    formatResult: getItemFormat,
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
    escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }
  });
});
```

Comment: after 5 years but your answer is just a life saver to me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide an ID that returns from your API like @itsmejodie said.
The other problem is that you have to provide `select2` `formatResult` and `formatSelection` functions, once you have it loaded from Ajax but you can't put `html` on that. e.g.:

```js
function format (item) { 
  return item.name; 
}

$(function() {
    $('#mySelect').select2({
      minimumInputLength: 2,
      placeholder: 'Search for an item',
      allowClear: true,
      ajax: {
        url: '/api/getItems',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        quietMillis: 250,
        data: function (term, page) {
          return {
            query: term
          };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
          return { results: data };
        }
      },
      formatResult: format,
      formatSelection: format
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For version 4 of Select2 use

```
processResults: function (data) {
```

instead of

```
results: function (data) {
```